# Sin, cos etc for Python 2 Decimal?

Tags: python, decimal, precision, trigonometry

In Python 2.6, I found that the Decimal equivalent of `sqrt(pi)` is

```
Decimal(pi).sqrt()
```

Is there anything like that for sin, cos or other (inverse) trigonometric functions?

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) only mention how to calculate `cos` and `sin` computationally. `Decimal(pi).cos()` doesn't exist nor does `from decimal import cos`

**Update**: the problem with using the default trigonometric functions is that it defeats the point of using `Decimal` if I convert them from float and back every time I want to calculate something. (Also typing `Decimal` around every calculation is annoying, but I guess I could make a wrapper function)

Comment: Why should Decimal module have trigonometric functions? And whats the problem with something like `Decimal(math.cos(val))` ?

Comment: Thanks for the question, I now clarified it in my question I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values of sin(a) and cos(a) are rational numbers only for particular angles (see [Link](https://planetmath.org/RationalSineAndCosine) ) so you can't store values of sin(a) or cos(a) as Decimals without losing precision. This defeats the purpose of converting sin and cos values to Decimal and having built-in functions that return sin and cos values as Decimals.

Moreover, you can't store all rational numbers as Decimal without losing precision because python's decimals are `(-1)**_sign * _int * 10**_exp` so the divisor of a rational number must be 10 for Decimal to store it with full precision.

I guess @carrot-top's mpmath advice or some numeric algorithm (like Taylor series approximation) is the best you can get.

Comment: The square root of a number isn't always rational either. The point is arbitrary precision, not infinite precision. Default functions don't even give you that.

Answer (score 6):

Please refer to this.

http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal-recipes

Comment: There is nothing built-in? Also what if I want another (inverse) trigonometric function, say `acos`?

Comment: As far as i can judge from your requirement, their is none built-in

Answer (score 6):

The Decimal library was intended to support properly rounded, base-10 arithmetic primarily for financial calculations where precise control of rounding is required. It was not intended to be a general-purpose arbitrary precision library.

If you need a general purpose arbitrary precision library, look at [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) or [gmpy2](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/).

Answer (score 4):

The trig functions are in the [math module](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions)

So:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(math.cos(0.1))
Decimal('0.99500416527802570954008842818439006805419921875')
```

If you are looking for multi precision math library in Python that supports trig functions, Decimal isn't it. Take a look at [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/). Mpmath supports [trig function](http://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/trigonometric.html) at arbitrary precision; decimal does not.

Comment: Seems rather pointless to use Decimal for extra precision, then convert it to float for every calculation...

Comment: @Mark: Decimal does not have trig functions.You either need to write them all in Python in Decimal class or settle for what Python's math module has. Or, use a library, like mpmath, that supports decimal like precision and has trig functions.

Comment: Because 0.1 is converted to a float first, it only has 53 bits of precision. So your result isn't accurate beyond 53 bits (around 17 digits).
` >>> gmpy2.cos(gmpy2.mpfr("0.1"))
mpfr('0.9950041652780257660955619878038702948385762254150840359593528',200)`

Comment: @casevh: Agreed, but the OP seemed to be looking (at first) for trig functions with Decimal. He did not mention (at first) arbitrary precision.